# javafx jscript runtime error

Tags: java, javafx, jscript

When running the sample java fx applications or making my own fx application in netbeans I get a message before the software runs that is titled Microsoft JScript runtime error. The message says Automation server can't create object. After I press okay I can get to my application. I have set up my java proxy and netbeans proxy and don't understand why this stop pops up. This happens when running throught command line (java -jar syntax) or through netbeans, the only way to avoid it is by running the application as through the java webstart. I am behind a firewall, is this related to my message or am I chasing down the wrong path?

Comment: It seems like it definately has something to do with security/proxy settings specifically becauuse the line in my code that creates the error is the line that tries to connect to a database.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any hints/ solutions?